# Where are the cliffs for Sagani's quest The Long Hunt?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

Sagani is looking for a guy named Persoq and all I know is that he is by "cliffs" overlooking the water (ocean?)

Any idea which zone that's in?

Answer (score 5):

First part takes place in Pearlwood Bluff but I had to go through Searing Falls to get there.

Answer (score 0):

Pearlwood Bluff, South south west of Wooded Plains map.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of old, but here goes. It's in Pearlwood Bluff, just to the southwestern side of this map near to where the wind elementals are.